# How to read variable amount of json data from url?

Tags: android, json

I am using the following code to read json data from url , but it has fixed length of 500 for the json data. How can I ensure that all the data(variable length) is always read.

```
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
InputStream is = null;
// Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
// web page content.
int len = 500;

try {
    URL url = new URL(myurl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();
    int response = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
    is = conn.getInputStream();

    // Convert the InputStream into a string
    String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
    return contentAsString;

// Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
// finished using it.
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        is.close();
    } 
}
}

public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
Reader reader = null;
reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
char[] buffer = new char[len];
reader.read(buffer);
return new String(buffer);
}
```

Thanks.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + newLine);
  }
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: At 3K+, I find it surprising that you are leaving a code only answer. SO discourages code only answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] data      = new byte[1024];
int    bytesRead = inputstream.read(data);

while(bytesRead != -1) {
  doSomethingWithData(data, bytesRead);

  bytesRead = inputstream.read(data);
}
```